# Making calls with Google Voice on Nexus 5

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-5, google-voice

I'm wondering how (if possible) I can use the Google Voice technology on my Nexus 5. I have it downloaded on my laptop and it works great, but I'm unable to download it on my Nexus 5 (the app is incompatible which is strange considering it's the flagship model).

Is there any way for me to get Google Voice on my phone?

Comment: The Google Voice app is compatible with the N5 (I have it installed on mine). How are you trying to install it, precisely? Are you located outside the US? Also, if you're looking to use it to make a VoIP call from your phone, similar to a PC, you should be aware that it does not support that.

Comment: Ahhhh I am outside of US (Canada) I tried downloading it on the play store. But if it doesn't support VoIP call I have no reason for using it.

Comment: The app is probably region locked to the US, I'd wager. Hopefully VoIP via Google Voice will be coming to Hangouts soon, [since they added it to the iOS app a little while back](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/3437917). Until then, it's just kind of a waiting game, unfortunately. There were a few third-party apps that would allow you to make VoIP calls using Google Voice, but Google blocked their access about a month ago.

Answer (score -1):

You should already have it pre-installed and enabled on your phone. Try saying "OK, Google" from the home screen. The steps [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6031948?hl=en&ref_topic=6032684) should give you an idea of how to enable it if it doesn't work.

Comment: That's not Google Voice, that's Google Now. Google Voice is a completely different service: http://www.google.com/googlevoice/about.html

Comment: Oh. Thought you wanted to be able to say "OK, Google: Call <x>".